# Iterating through lists of lists in Python while keeping data structure

Tags: python, list-comprehension, sublist

How can I iterate through lists of lists while keeping a lists data structure?
Here is the case:

```
w = [3, 3]
z = [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2]]
lst = []

for x, y in zip(w, z):
    for u in y:
        lst.append(u+x)

print (lst)
```

What I get is: *`[4, 4, 4, 5, 5]`*
What I want is: *`[[4, 4, 4], [5, 5]]`*

I need to have the original list data structure.

Comment: This code does not run w/o error.

Comment: First, this code returns an error, I think `z` in the second loop is `y`.

Comment: Edited to fix it. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the information available on the question, I think you should traverse both lists with an `O(nxm)` time complexity approximately adding the corresponding values between lists in order to preserve original data structure:

```
w = [3, 3]
z = [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2]]
lst = []

for i in z:
    for j in w:
        lst.append([a+j for a in i])
    
print (lst)
```

**Output:**

```
[[4, 4, 4], [4, 4, 4], [5, 5], [5, 5]]
```

Also, if you want it in one line, you can extend the use of list comprehension:

```
w = [3, 3]
z = [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2]]
lst = []

lst = [[a+j for a in i] for j in w for i in z]
print (lst)
```

**Output:** *(In this case the order is changed, you can invert the execution order of the for loops to get the correct one if needed)*

```
[[4, 4, 4], [5, 5], [4, 4, 4], [5, 5]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```py
w = [3, 3]
z = [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2]]
lst = []

for x, y in zip(w, z):
    for _ in range(len(z)):
        lst.append([u+x for u in y])

print(lst)
```

**OUTPUT:** `[[4, 4, 4], [4, 4, 4], [5, 5], [5, 5]]`

Answer (score 0):

As a one-liner:

```py
import itertools

w = [3, 3]
z = [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2]]

lst = [[x + val for val in vals] for x, vals in itertools.product(w, z)]

print (lst)
```

Output:

```
[[4, 4, 4], [5, 5], [4, 4, 4], [5, 5]]
```